# How to fix "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm using Intellij to develop my Spark app using the Scala language. While running the code this error is throwing in the terminal.
My Scala version in built.sbt is 2.11.8.
My Java version is 1.8.0_231

I tried downgrading my Java version from 13 to Java 8.

```
19/11/02 09:31:25 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/C:/Users/iraja/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.6.5/hadoop-auth-2.6.5.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
19/11/02 09:31:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2430)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2430)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2430)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:295)
    at sparkrdd.RDDTempData$.main(RDDTempData.scala:9)
    at sparkrdd.RDDTempData.main(RDDTempData.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3720)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:50)
    ... 17 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using?

Comment: My Hadoop version is 2.7.4

Comment: Are you sure?  Are you sure that you are using it in all of the right places?  Apparently this bug is **fixed** in 2.7.4.  If not, try 3.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Hadoop issue that fails to parse some java.version. It has been fixed from Hadoop-2.7.4

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26134